# NSView - setCornerRadius curve all 4 corners

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, drawrect, cornerradius

I am working on a Mac app and need a custom NSView with 4 rounded corners. Everything I have tried either produces no results, or only curves the botton two edges of the `NSView`. Is there a way to curve all 4 corners of an `NSView`?

I tried making a custom class and used the `initWithFrame` method which produces no results what so ever. I then tried the `drawRect` method which curves the bottom two corners only:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    
    [self setWantsLayer:YES];
    [self.layer setFrame:self.frame];
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
}
```

How can I curve all four corners? And does anyone know why developing for the Mac is so much harder than on iOS. Why does even the most basic task always require a custom class (i.e.: setting the NSView background colour or running the equivalent of a `UIViewAnimation`....).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This three lines give me rounded corners and red background for the `testView` of type `NSView` linked as an outlet from storyboard in `viewDidLoad` of a ViewController, no subclassing needed:

```
_testView.wantsLayer = YES;
_testView.layer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
_testView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.;
```

**Edit**

Not all corners were rounded because of this line:

```
[self.layer setFrame:self.frame];
```

Basically you don't need it, you set proper layer frame with this line:

```
[self setWantsLayer:YES];
```

If you do want to set layer frame explicitely, you want to use

```
[self.layer setFrame:self.bounds];
```

Read about difference between `frame` and `bounds`.
And aforementioned code works in `drawRect:` too.

Comment: I see thanks. That worked for me, not sure why subclassing didn't work. Oh well thanks anyway.